# Swift #selector referencing to an Objective-C method

Tags: swift, xcode7.3

As it possible to conclude in swift 2.2 version it will be possible to reference to the Objective-C method via #selector.

```
let sel = #selector(UIView.insertSubview(_:at:)) // produces the Selector "insertSubview:atIndex:"
```

So previously we wear using name of the method like simple string : `"doBangBang"` and call it `Selector("doBangBang")` and now we should use it like reference to the method `MyClass.doBangBang()` and with usage of key word `#selector(MyClass.doBangBang())`? Does this feature deprecate `Selector`? And what benefits are from this improvments except of reducing amount of the functions that were perform with wrong name?

Comment: See "Motivation" in https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0022-objc-selectors.md . Also note that this is introduced mainly for interoperability with older Objective-C frameworks because in new code closures are a far better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature effectively deprecates using `Selector("methodName")` and also just using `"methodName"` or `"methodName:"` for selectors.

The main benefit is that you can't make typos in the method string anymore, as you already state in the question.

Imagine a method with a selector:

```
..., selector: "myMethod:")
```

What happens when you typo?

```
..., selector: "mymethod:")
```

It crashes.

With the new system it's type-safe: the compiler can check that the method you're calling actually exists - no more typos, no more calling non-existing functions:

```
..., selector: #selector(myMethod))
```

because the compiler can check the types. We also get auto-suggestion and auto-completion from Xcode and all the niceties coming with type-safe operations.